# JBoss EAP 7: increasing the second level cache size for a JPA application

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, jboss7.x, infinispan

Given JBoss 7 and an application with enabled second level caching in persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.JndiInfinispanRegionFactory" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.cachemanager" value="java:jboss/infinispan/container/hibernate" />
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.default_cache_concurrency_strategy" value="transactional" />
```

Given also @Cacheable on some entities
and @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL) on some relations.

Because performance is bad I turned on

```
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
```

in persistence.xml.

In the JPA statistics I see lots of cache misses, even for entities I accessed seconds ago. So I assume the cache size is not big enough. How can I increase it?

I tried

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.eviction.max_entries" value="200000"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.expiration.lifespan" value="1800000"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.expiration.max_idle" value= "1200000"/>
```

in persistence.xml but still the same with the misses.

Clarification: Sorry, I meant JBoss EAP 7 (from 2016), not JBoss AS 7 (from 2011).

Comment: It's seems all correct to me, try changing region factory eg:
```<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory" />```

Comment: You can try by entity eg: ```<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.com.model.entity.YourEntity.expiration.lifespan" value= "86400000" />```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use custom regions (through `org.hibernate.annotations.Cache`), setting `hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.eviction.max_entries` is the correct approach. You can even disable eviction completely by setting that to -1.

You can see a cache miss after you've modified the entity; the cache is invalidated after each write and expects to be refilled upon next read. The other option is that something is calling [evictEntityRegions](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cache/spi/access/RegionAccessStrategy.java#L131) or another operation that ends up calling [evictAll](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cache/spi/access/RegionAccessStrategy.java#L148) or [removeAll](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cache/spi/access/RegionAccessStrategy.java#L131). You'd have to debug into these methods or install Byteman rules to find out the culprit if this is the case.